# In R: find a percent match between two groups of columns

Tags: r

all. I am new to R. I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
    SUBJ STIM      A1        A2       A3      A4      W1      W2       W3      W4
26     1  I26    call        to    other classes    copy   extra    class   notes
27     1  I27    cats    should       go   grass     cow  chewed     long   grass
28     1  I28   crowd    yelled      out   cheer   crowd  yelled      out   cheer
29     1  I29     dad    drinks      hot     tea     dad  drinks      hot     tea
```

Where W1 - W4 are predicted values and A1 - A4 are actual values. I would like to find the percent "correct" for my actual values, i.e. the match between columns A1 - A4 as a group and columns W1 - W4 as a group. Row order matters.

I was able to use

```
paste0(round(100*length(intersect(dataset$A1, dataset$W1))/nrow(dataset)), "%")
```

from another question here to get the percent match by row between individual columns A1 and W1, but there must be an efficient way to find the match between the A columns and W columns as groups?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subset to the data to the A columns and then to the W columns, check which are the same with `==`, then get the percent which are the same with `mean`

```
pct <- mean(df[, paste0('A', 1:4)] == df[, paste0('W', 1:4)])
pct
# [1] 0.5625
scales::percent(pct)
# [1] "56.2%"
```